# Javascript's .toString(16) in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, tostring

I'd like to do the same as JavaScript's `.toString(16)` but in PHP :

```
var n = 200000002713419;
console.log(n.toString(16));
```

This returns `b5e6211de74b`.
How can I achieve the same with PHP ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `dechex()` will get you part of the way there, but note the limitations in the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php

Comment: @zerkms, I couldn't sleep with the guilt of submitting one that would fail the given usage case :^)

Comment: @rjz: among "good dreams" and "at least +40 rep points" I would choose the latter ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use PHP's built-in function [`base_convert()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) or [`dechex()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php):

```
$hex = dechex(12321313); // bc0221
$hex = base_convert(4353454654, 10, 16); // 37c723e
```

Comment: `base_convert()` did the job, but I actually have to convert a string to get the same result as javascript's `toString(16)` :
`base_convert('200000002713419', 10, 16);`